# Unable to generate POJO from WSDL using Apache CXF Library Maven

Tags: java, maven, cxf, java-11

I am trying to convert WSDL file to Java using the Apache CXF library, however I am getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.0:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project wsdl2javademo: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.0:wsdl2java failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.0:wsdl2java: javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/HexBinaryAdapter
```

Here is the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl2javademo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <cxf.version>3.2.0</cxf.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried to use multiple sources with different logics however none of those seems to be solving the purpose.

Trying different version, adding dependencies etc.  Even tried going through the sample project: https://github.com/dimitrisli/Wsdl2Java